# Convexity of a multivariate linear equation

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

i am new to mathematics. I want to know if the following function is jointly convex in term of X and h? where X $\in $ discrete complex set and h and n has a gaussian distribution with zero mean and unit variance.

$\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf y}^p\\ {\bf y}^d_1 
\\ \vdots
\\ {\bf y}^d_N
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\bf \Phi \\ \bf \Phi X_1 \\ \vdots \\ \bf \Phi X_N\end{bmatrix} \bf \alpha\bf{h} + \bf{n} $

Comment: $\alpha \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 0):

No. Only linear equalities represent a convex set, and this equality is bilinear in $h$ and $X$

Comment: Thanks. I have another question.  In order to prove that that a quadratic function is convex: $x^H Ax$ , $A$ needs to be positive semi definite. 
Where $A = \Phi^H \Phi $ and $\Phi$ is a $n \times k$ matrix with possibly $k$ linearly independent columns.
How to prove that A is positive semi definite? @Johan Lofberg